# Does MongoDB fail silently if I don't check error codes?

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering if any persistence failure will go undetected if I don't check error codes? If so, what's the right way to write fast (asynchronously) while still detecting errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't check for errors, your update is only fireAndForget. You'll indeed miss all errors which could arise. Please see MongoDB [WriteConcerns](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.2/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html) for the available write modes in MongoDB (sorry I always fail to find the official, non driver related documentation, I really should bookmark it).
So with NORMAL you'll get at least connectivity errors, with NONE no exceptions at all. If you want to be informed of exceptions you have to use one of the other modes, which differ only in the persistence guarantee they give you.
You can't detect errors when running asynchronous, as this is against the intention. Your connection which sent the write operation, may be already closed or reused, so you can't sent it through that connection. Further more only your actual code knows what to do if it fails. As mongoDB doesn't offer some remote procedure call to asynchronous inform you of updates you'll have to wait until the write finished to a given stage.
 So the fastest, but most unrelieable is SAFE, where the write only happened to memory. JOURNAL gives you the security that it was written at least to disk. With FSYNC you'll have those changes persisted on your db on disk. REPLICA that a least two replicas have written it, and MAJORITY that more than half of your replicas have written it(by three replicas which should be the default this doesn't differ).

The only chance I see to have something like asynchronous, is to have a separate Thread who is performing all write operations synchronous. This thread you could handle the actual update as well as a class which is called in case of a failure to perform the needed operations to handle this failure. But I don't think that this is good application design.

Comment: Here's some further information on using "getLastError", which as Phil hinted at will ensure MongoDB waits for the response - http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command. And another - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/replica-sets/#are-write-operations-durable-without-getlasterror. Finally, here's the official driver documentation - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/drivers/.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, depending on the error, it can fail silently if you don't check the returned error code. It's necessary to wait for error checking. Your only other option would be for your app to occasionally tell the user "oops, remember when I acted like I saved your data a moment ago? Well, not really."

Comment: I'm not sure about the last statement. Part of what makes Mongo fast is the writes are buffered and written asynchronously. It's my understanding that if you check the error code, it will necessarily have to block until things are written to disk. Is this understanding wrong?

Comment: you're right. Except for network errors, you have to wait that the write has taken place at mongod to be sure that there are no exceptions. As this causes you to perform synchronous instead of asynchronous it will slow down your application, but not the server(or not that much, as most of the checks would be needed anyway). Please see my post for more details

Comment: What? And forsake the discussion thread? That's almost as bad as deleting my comment.